# How do I call animateAlongsideTransition in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, ios8

I've tried so many combinations in order to call `animateAlongSideTransition` in Swift for a transition coordinator. I feel like I'm missing something very stupid.

If I want to call this (from Swift docs):

```
func animateAlongsideTransition(_ animation: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext!) -> Void)!,
                     completion completion: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext!) -> Void)!) -> Bool
```

How would I do it? I just want to pass some things in the animation block and nothing in the completion block.

Answer (score 7):

This is definitely what you want to do:

```
coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({ context in
        // do whatever with your context
        context.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
    }, completion: nil)
```

You can also omit the parameters if you use variables like `$0` for the first implicit parameter and so

```
coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({
        $0.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
    }, completion: nil)
```

The `in` syntax surprises at first, but you have to learn it only once :)

- The curly brackets defines the block inside the function
- You use `in` to separate the parameters from the block body
- But as I said above, you can omit the parameters by using `$0`, `$1`, `$2` and so...

It seems that there's a more verbose syntax, but it definitely not fits the Swift spirit (and I'm too lazy to post it there)

Hope it helps *(and I don't forget anything...)*

**Edit:**

Another pro tip is when the block is the only parameter, you can even omit the parentheses
*(The next will not work, but it's to figure the idea)*

```
coordinator.animateAlongsideTransition{
        $0.viewControllerForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey)
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You do it like this (at least in Swift 1.2):

```
transitionCoordinator.animateAlongsideTransition({context in //things to animate, for example: view.alpha = 0.5
}, completion: nil)
```